# Cakephp Be able to do math with a selected text input option from form

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I want to be able to do math with select text box. I am not sure what is the best way to handle this situation only thing I have thought of is either A) Update two fields in the database or B) Have the input field be seen as text but held as a number in the database.

See the following:

New Quote = 20%

Quote Sent = 50%

Quote Received = 60%

Negotiate = 80%

The problem with B is that when trying to view the stage in the quote > view.ctp I see it as a number.

The point is to be able to do the following math. OpportunityAmount = amount * (quote_stage_assigned / 100)

I added a field to the quote form called stage. I added it to add, edit, and view.

In the view I have

View > Edit

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('quote_stage_assigned', array('label' => 'Stage Assigned',
                    'options' => array(
                        'New Quote' =>'New Quote',
                        'Quote Sent' =>'Quote Sent',
                    'Quote Received' =>'Quote Received'
                    'Negotiate' =>'Negotiate'
                        )); ?>
```

View > Add

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('opportunity_stage_assigned', array('label' => 'Stage Assigned',
            'options' => array('New Quote', 'Quote Sent', 'Quote Received, Negotiate')
            )); ?>
```

View > View

```
    <?php echo $thisQuote['Quote']['quote_stage_assigned'];?>
```

In the Model

```
        'quote_stage_assigned' => array(
            'between' => array(
                'rule'    => array('between', 1, 64),
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Stage Assigned must be between 1 and 64 characters long'
            )
        ),
```

In the controller

```
    $this->stages = array('0'=>'Lost'
                        , '20' => 'New Quote'
                        , '50' => 'Quote Sent'
                        , '60' => 'Quote Received'
                        , '80' => 'Negotiate');
```

Comment: So what you actually want is to store a different value in the database than you want to display? And that there are only a few  fixed 'translations'. I would use constants in the model and make a few translate functions...

Comment: See [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) for example.